# Using react how do i get the value of a select dropdown that is held in a const?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React. I have tried to keep components in separate files. So, I have:

1. SaveDocument (class)
2. PersonList (const)
3. Person (const)

PersonList represents a dropdown of persons. I am trying to figure out how to get the value of the select dropdown in the SaveDocument class (i.e. when they click 'Save Changes').

How can i get the value of the select dropdown when the user clicks click Save?

Code below:

### PersonList.js

```
import React from "react";
import Person from "./../model/Person";

const PersonList = props => {
  return (
    <div key="PersonList">
      <select className="col-6">
        {props.persons.map(person => <Person key={person.id} {...person} />)}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PersonList;
```

### Person.js

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const Person = person => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(person));

  return (
    <option id="{person.id}">{person.firstName + " " + person.lastName}</option>
  );
};

Document.defaultProps = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: ""
};

export default Person;
```

### SaveDocument.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import postDocument from "./../rest/PostDocument";
import fetchPersons from "./../rest/FetchPersons";
import PersonList from "./../components/PersonList";
import ShowDatePicker from "./../components/ShowDatePicker";

class SaveDocument extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [],
    personFromSelect: ''
  };

  cachePersons = personInfo => {
    console.log(">> persons" + personInfo);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      persons: personInfo
    }));
  };

  resetFields () {
    console.log("reset");
    console.log(this.keys.PersonList.value);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("mounted");

    fetchPersons.callApi(this.cachePersons);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="modal fade"
        id="basicExampleModal"
        tabIndex="-1"
        role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                Save document
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-4 text-left">Document Date:</div>
                <div className="col-6">
                  <ShowDatePicker />
                </div>
              </div>
              <br />
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-4 text-left">Person From:</div>
                <PersonList persons={this.state.persons} />
              </div>
              <br />
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-4 text-left">Comments:</div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      id="commentsBox"
                      placeholder="Comments"
                      onKeyPress={event => {
                        if (event.key === "Enter") {
                        }
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-secondary"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                onClick={() => this.resetFields()}
              >
                Close
              </button>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={() => postDocument.callApi(this.props)}
              >
                Save changes
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SaveDocument;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) (where the input state is handled directly by the DOM element) are generally not advisable and make it harder to manage and reason about your app state. I'd recommend you change to a [controlled component](http://controlled%20component), where the state of your input is managed by React and the DOM simply renders that state.

**PersonList.js**:

Note that the `<select>` element receives its selected value from `props`, as well as a callback handler for when the user makes a change.

```
const PersonList = props => {
  return (
    <div key="PersonList">
      <select className="col-6" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChangeCallback} >
        {props.persons.map(person => <Person key={person.id} {...person} />)}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Person.js**:

Note that it now has a `value` prop so that onchange events know what the new value will be, and `<select>` knows which option to display based on `value`.

```
const Person = person => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(person));

  return (
    <option value={person.id} id="{person.id}">{person.firstName + " " + person.lastName}</option>
  );
};
```

**SaveDocument.js**:

Note that you're now keeping the dropdown select state in React state and passing it down to the child component PersonList, along with the callback handler for updating state.

```
...
onChangeCallback = (e) => {
    this.setState({personValue: e.target.value});
}
cachePersons = personInfo => {
    console.log(">> persons" + personInfo);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      persons: personInfo,
      personValue: personInfo[0].id
    }));
};
render() {
    ...
        <PersonList
            persons={this.state.persons}
            value={this.state.personValue}
            onChangeCallback={this.onChangeCallback}
        />
    ...
}
```

Now you are actually keeping the select state of your dropdown menu in your parent component, SaveDocument, and passing it down into the list. The list simply renders the dropdown menu with the appropriately selected value (from state) and provides a callback for when it changes. Now the state of your dropdown lives inside React state and is easily accessible from inside SaveDocument when the user clicks the "save" button, instead of ambiguously living in the DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Add a prop to PersonList:

```
<PersonList onChangePerson={this.props.onChangePerson} />
```

Add an event handler for onChangePerson to SaveDocument.js and don’t forget to bind this in your constructor.

```
onChangePerson(event) {
    var value = event.target.value
}
this.onChangePerson = this.onChangePerson.bind(this);
```

On the select add the onChange event

```
<select onChange={this.props.onChangePerson}></select>
```

You would then setState in the onChangePerson event to save your currently selected person and then when the user clicked Save, you would reference this.state.selectedPerson for example.